# How to Parse rows of only first child table using Jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

I'm having html which looks something like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <table>
             <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Header 1</td>
                    <td>Value 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Header 2 2</td>
                    <td>Value 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Header 3</td>
                    <td>
                        Values 3 should be complete column
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>This should go into Value 3</th>
                                    <th>This should go into Value 3 too, including its table</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Again Value 3</td>
                                    <td>Again into Value 3 too, including its table</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Header 4</td>
                    <td>Value 4</td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
        </table>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to create a map such that the first  from each row of table at level 1 becomes key and second  becomes value, no matter what is there in second td. Problem which I'm facing is that if there is a complete table lying in second , it's rows are also getting picked up when I actually want it as a value. The code I'm using is this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlText);
Elements table = doc.select("table");
Element innerTable;
if(table!=null && table.size()>1){
    innerTable = table.get(1);
}else{
    innerTable = table.get(0);
}
Elements rows = innerTable.select("tr");
for(Element row : rows){
    Elements cols = row.select("td");
    String headerFromHTML = cols.get(0).text();
    String valueFromHTML = cols.get(1).html();
    System.out.println(headerFromHTML+","+valueFromHTML);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Header 1, Value 1
Header 2, Value 2
Header 3, Value 3 should be complete td<table><tbody><tr><th>This should go into Value 3</th><th>This should go into Value 3 too, including its table</th></tr><tr><td>Again Value 3</td><td>Again into Value 3 too, including its table</td></tr></tbody></table>
Header 4, Value 4
```

But actual output does not yield this. The row actually contains inner tr also and I dont get desired result. Infact, due to th, it also throws an exception (which could be handled but this tr should actually come in value).
How can I modify my code. Please help.

Comment: th=table header|tr=table row|td=table data|tbody= table body| value 3 is not closed properly also you probably don't need the inner Tbody unless you are making multiple tables. also if you can provide an example of the output it might help.

Comment: @CS_STEM Thank you for the reply CS. I'm getting these htmls from client and have multiple tables inside td. I've given the expected output above. I'll just put it in a hashmap with headers as key and values as respective vale.

Answer (score 0):

for one most of the tags are in the wrong place. 
for two you have table defined too many times. 
for three the organization needs improving. 
for four here is how it should basically look

```
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>     
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>     
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>     
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

keep in mind that HTML displays elements in order unless changed by another language

Comment: Thank you for the explanation CS. I'm getting this html from my client and they have many inner tables in the content.So I can't change its format. But I believe that there can be a workaround as the tags are well formatted.